# How do I change fish syntax highlighting for specific commands?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, fish

The fish shell does syntax highlighting while I type commands. For example, unclosed strings appear as red, closed strings appear as yellow. 
My question is: Can I interact with the syntax highlighting for specific commands?

I'd like to achieve the following behavior: When I type

```
git commit -m "Some commit message"
```

the message string should get a different color when it's longer than 50 chars.

Answer (score 2):

This is a sweet idea, but unfortunately it can't be done in fish! The syntax highlighting has to run without executing any shell script, so there's no way to inject custom logic.

Comment: I was wondering if this anwer is still correct as of version 3.1.2?